# How to make title of shared link value a varible in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

i am creating a share functionality in my app. when a user shares a link to a specific shop i want the link to contain the name of the shop in the title card in the shared link.

this image should make you understand what i need better.
Below image shows a static `title tag <>` and below it a non static title coming from the shared link shops name. but it is not appearing in the link, whilst the static title is showing.

how can i make the variable title show in my shared link?

[image: This image shows what i need]

here is my code:
in my app.js file:

```
const shopName = snapshot.get('name');
document.getElementById('titleShop').innerHTML = shopName + " |";
```

in my html page:

```
<title id="titleShop"></title>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

any help? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the page title with javascript after it has been loaded.

Whatsapp probably does not elaborate the javascript on the page, it only load the html and extract the title from there. You need to include the shop nome on the initial html